# How to install package from launchpad.net?

Tags: apt, package-management, ssh, ppa, openssh

I want to install recent version of `ssh` available from https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openssh to enable `-J` option (not sure whether `-J` is available in particular version, but there is `1:7.2p2-4ubuntu2.1` version in `16.04`). There is PPA term and many information of how to install them. In the case of mentioned link I can't find what is `user/repo` pair.

When I search I get the links as above, not a PPA. But themselves not contain an information of how to install, say, `1:7.5p1-7ubuntu2` version of `ssh`. So, how to deal with them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're probably better off not adding the PPA as it might break other software versions when you run `apt update`, and you will likely have to use `apt dist-upgrade` to install them. These are specific to different versions of Ubuntu, the link you gave is to the source code packages.

I'm guessing you don't want to compile the binaries from source, so you could try downloading a more recent deb package of ssh-client. The following is experimental, so please note that trying this is at your own risk, I'm not sure what version of Ubuntu you're using, nor if the recent binaries are compatible. If you want to use a newer version of ssh-client you're better off compiling the source, but this can be very tedious if you're not familiar which is why I've provided the steps below.

Access [this page.](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial-updates/openssh-client)

Select the version you're after (I'm guessing amd64 if you are using 64-bit or i386 if you are using 32-bit, please check your architecture by running `lscpu` in the terminal if you're not sure)

Then click the link that looks like:

```
security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu
```

You can then install the package using the GUI by opening the .deb file that you've downloaded.

If the above breaks your installation, you can open the .deb file again and uninstall. Then run `sudo apt install ssh-client` to reinstall the default version.

[Direct link to amd64 package](http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssh/openssh-client_7.2p2-4ubuntu2.1_amd64.deb)

[Direct link to i386 package](http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssh/openssh-client_7.2p2-4ubuntu2.1_i386.deb)

Comment: `1:7.2p2-4ubuntu2.1` is current version in `16.04`

Comment: The `-J` option is around since Yakkety, which had `openssh-client_7.3p1-1`. I'd use the currect [Zesty package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/zesty/openssh-client), see [the manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/en/man1/ssh.1.html) to get sure.